# pass ref from reusble component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to pass the ref from a child component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Text from "./Text";
import { TextInput, View, I18nManager } from "react-native";
import colors from "../styles/colors";
 export default class Input extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <Text>
        {this.props.label}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <TextInput
      {...this.props}
      placeholder={this.props.label}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to focus on next input with this reusable component but it's not working.

```
<Input
        label={'username'}
        returnKeyType={"next"}
        onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.password.focus()}
/>
<Input label={'password'} ref={'password'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";   

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    this.passwordRef.current.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="email" />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>next</button>
        <hr />
        <input ref={this.passwordRef} placeholder="password" />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0olp12q8jw).

Another way, using child:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="email" />
        <Child passwordRef={this.passwordRef} />
        <hr />
        <input ref={this.passwordRef} placeholder="password" />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Child = ({ passwordRef }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => passwordRef.current.focus()}>focus</button>;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Short answer: `this.ref.current` instead of `this.ref`.

Comment: it's working but isn't there another short way of doining this ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, shorter than what? String refs in React are going to be deprecated, so it's better to use `createRef()`.

Comment: he means  react-native not just react.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `React.forwardRef`:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <View>
    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <Text>{this.props.label}</Text>
    </View>
    <TextInput {...this.props} ref={ref} placeholder={this.props.label} />
  </View>
));
export default Input;
```

And once you've defined `Input` using `forwardRef`, you can use the `ref` attribute as you normally . would:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  inputRef = React.createRef();
  focusInput = () => {
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return <Input ref={this.inputRef} />;
  }
}
```